# how to change the frequency my buffallo router w/ddwrt uses?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

how to change the frequency my buffallo router w/ddwrt uses?

getting bad connections in one of my rooms in a house.  old router didn't have any issue so I am guessing it could be a frequency issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you mean channel?

Log on to the web interface and select the **Wireless** tab.  Select the channel you wish to use (or set it to Auto) then hit **Save** followed by **Apply**.

Note that beyond channel there are many other possible reasons for connection problems, including the aerials, power settings and physical location.